# Azure Powershell Scripts are not working after hosting in IIS

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Azure powershell script files(PS1) are not working after hosting in IIS.
We invoke PS1 files from C#(using Runspace and pipeline).
The PS1 files are working fine if I debug through powershell ISE.But following logs found after hosting in IIS.

yet to invoke pipe line

Invoked pipe line

result count is : 0

An internal error occurred.

An error occurred while sending the request.

However,when the APIs are debugged,the pipeline does not throw any error.
Is there any environment issue such as publishsettings file? How to resolve this kind of exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the issue is the user that the commands are running as under IIS.  The commandlets create and read from a subscription database in the user's appdata directory, and I'm guessing that the user configured for your w3wp process has no such directory.

You can try running your iis app pool as a user that has a set of imported subscriptions, or importing subscriptions as part of your script.

Comment: Dear Mark Cowlishaw..thanks a lot for the response.Now we narrowed down the problem.The problem is not with the pipe line.We have written logs inside PS1 script files itself and ensured that all the paramers are supplied as required.Forexample,"Get-AzureSqlDatabase -ServerName $ServerName " requires only server name and  one subscription selection.We ensured that the server name and proper subscription is selected.But still we DID NOT get any output.Infact,None of the PS1 file produces any output.Please let us know if you know anything about this.